# Set label in UITableViewCell to grow but with max width

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, autoresize

I have a UITableView that has a label along the left with some text, and I want the label to grow when it is displayed on an iPad, or when the device goes landscape, but I have a button on the far right of the table cell, and using the autoresizing mask seems to make it overlap with the button. Is there an easy way to have it autoresize only until it gets close to the edge of the button, or do I have to handle setting a new frame for the label manually for each case?

Thanks...

Comment: Is autoresize a requirement? As much as I disliked it to begin with, autolayout is the perfect solution for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, auto layout isn't an option. I'm not sure why, I was just told specifically not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

WhkBased on my experience auto layout should work well here. While auto layout has improved a great deal, it's not perfect. While its a lot more work, doing the manual resize will guarantee you will get the result you want every time.